# Going to automate UI test on WinCE 5.0 - how to obtain MTK/DATK from Microsoft?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, windows-ce, ui-automation, msdn

Got a device running WinCE 5.0 to test, wanna automate UI.

Found this piece of doc 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa463259.aspx
which is kinda weak, but that's at least something.

But what I don't get - is where can I download a DATK tool/library itself? MSDN gives no clue, either with subscription or without it.

Can someone shed any light on it?

Comment: You probably need to get with the manufacturer of the device. IIRC, WinCE platforms (SDKs/DDKs) are built by the OEMs with a tool that Microsoft provides (only) to them.